# Jquery on keyup once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to trigger another alert when I input some text on next time?
For example:
1. put some text 
2. alert triggered 
3. put some text again 
4. alert trigger again

EDIT: I don't want to keep trigger the alert for every time i input, what i trying to do is... lets say I key in "abcd", the function should just trigger once. Then I click everywhere on the screen. Later, I key in "dddd" again in the textbox, the function trigger again for once

EDIT 2: Sry guys, maybe my requirement a bit confusing, i just edit the code and re-explain to illustrate my real case. So, first, i key in "abcd" on textbox, the tooltip should trigger once on first letter of "a". Then i click everywhere of the screen, the tooltip disappear. Next, I key in again "gfffee", the tooltip should appear again on first letter of "g".

```
<input type="text" id="test">
<input type="button" id="tool">


$('#test').one("keyup", function(){ 
    $('#tool').tooltip("show");
});

$('#tool').tooltip({
        placement: "bottom",
        trigger: "focus",
        title: "Click here",
    });
```

ANSWER:
Thanks everyone for helping me, I managed solve it based on combination of everyone answer.

```
    count = 0;

    $('#test').on("change", function(){ 
        count = 0;
    });

    $('#test').on("keyup", function(){  

        if(count == 0)
        {
            $('#tool').tooltip("show");
            count = 1;
        }
    });

    $('#tool').tooltip({
        placement: "bottom",
        trigger: "focus",
        title: "Click here",
    });

  <input type="text" id="test">
  <input type="button" id="tool">
```

Comment: use `.one()` will trigger only once for event

Comment: how to trigger another once for next time?

Comment: remove one i guess

Comment: Yeah instead of .one use .on

Comment: use `.on()` not `.one()` if you dont want to run `.keyup()` once

Comment: Define `next time`.  When does `this time` end?

Comment: I don't want to keep trigger the alert for every time i input, what i trying to do is... lets say I key in "abcd", the function should just trigger once. Then I click everywhere on the screen. Later, I key in "dddd" again in the textbox, the function trigger again for once

Comment: *"Then I click everywhere on the screen."* - Everywhere? Do you mean "elsewhere"? Anyway, when you enter "abcd", do you want the alert immediately after the "a", or when the user stops typing?

Comment: why don't you use the [`blur`](https://api.jquery.com/blur/) event based on your requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var triggered = 0; // or false

$('#test').on('input', function() {
    if(triggered == 0) {
        alert('whatever message here');
        triggered++;
    }
});

$('#test').on('blur', function() {
    // reset the triggered value to 0
    triggered = 0;
});
```

Comment: You give me an idea how to do this.. thx so much, will update my answer

Comment: Glad to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

on input clear the timer with `clearTimeout(userTimer);` then start new timer with `setTimeout(doneType, maxTimer*1000);` the maxTimer is in sec of your choose (2s here) if timeout call the function `doneType`

```js
var userTimer;
var maxTimer = 2;

//on input, clear the timer and start new timer
$('#test').on('input', function () {
  clearTimeout(userTimer);
  userTimer = setTimeout(doneType, maxTimer*1000);
});

function doneType() {
  alert('keep type?');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="test">
```

Comment: You don't need the `input` handler as well as the `keyup` handler. One or the other is enough. (Using `input` is probably better given that users can edit fields without using the keyboard.)

Comment: @nnnnnn thanks, you are right, just in one case, it might confuse the user if the user pressing a key for 2sec and the doneType will be triggered.

Comment: When I tried your demo (after your update) in Chrome, if I press and hold a key no alert is displayed until after I let go regardless of how long I hold it for.

Comment: @nnnnnn on my Macbook Chrome I have that problem, but it is an edge case, I would prefer clean code =D

Comment: Thx for helping. I have edited the post a bit, can you have a look and see if there is better answer than this?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no deterministic way to figure out when you are done with your input, using just the `keyup` event. But you can try debounce. I've added [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org) to use [debouce](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce), but feel free to use your own implementation or another library. From the debounce docs of underscore

> Useful for implementing behavior that should only happen after the input has stopped arriving

You can play around with the wait time to suit your needs. I've made it 500 ms

```js
$('#test').on("keyup", _.debounce(function() {
  alert("test");
}, 500));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="test">
```

An excellent explanation of debounce [here](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/#article-header-id-0)

### Alternate solution

Another possible solution is to attach a `blur` handler, which will execute if clicked outside your `input`

```js
$("#test").on("blur", function(e) {
  alert("Test")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="test">
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use the onchange function? From your edit it seems like this would be more appropriate for your use case.

So

```
$('#test').on("change", function(){ 
    alert("test");
});
```

Comment: thx for helping. onchange seem not the case for me (this only works if the input/keyup is end), I have edited the post to make the question clearer.